# How to pass variables to a HEREDOC in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I want to do something like this:

```
$ NAME=John
$ cat << '==end' > test
My name is $NAME
==end

$ cat test
My name is John
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
cat <<EOF > test
My name is $NAME
EOF
```

or even

```
cat <<==end > test
My name is $NAME
==end
```

Worked for me.

Looks like when you take `==end` in the `'` variable doesn't substitute.

The [Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents) section of the manual says:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>       <<[-]word
>               here-document
>       delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or
> pathname expansion is performed on *word*.  If any characters in *word* are
> quoted,  the  *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on word, and the
> lines in the here-document are not expanded.  If *word* is unquoted,  all
> lines  of  the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion. [...]

Comment: You can also use double-quotes (`cat << "==end" > test`), but hard-quotes prevent substitution indeed.

Comment: Double quotes also prevent parameter expansion